# Passphrase popup with EGIT and GITHUB through SSH

Tags: eclipse, git, github, ssh, egit

I have been working with EGit and JGit. I am trying to push some files to the server using JGit by right clicking the project and then doing a `Push to Upstream`.

Here is the popup that requests for the passphrase:

[image]

Where does this popup come from? How do I configure my EGIT inoder to avoid this request for passphrase popup?

The process I use to get to this popup is: `right click  -> Team -> Push to Upstream -> I get a popup asking for Passphrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eclipse to generate a new key - Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> SSH2 -> Key Management

Copy the generated public key to the remote repo

Click the [Save Private Key] button without entering a passphrase

RESTART ECLIPSE

This might not ask you for passphrase again.

***Don't forget to configure your Fecth/Push Configuration.(Team->Remote->Configure Fetch/Push from Upstream)
[image: Configure Push to Upstream]

Change the URI***